# Unable to ABORT Schedule job

Tags: scheduled-apex

I am trying to abort Salesforce schedule job using below script

```
list<CronTrigger> con=[SELECT CreatedById,CreatedDate,CronExpression,CronJobDetailId,EndTime,Id,LastModifiedById,NextFireTime,OwnerId,PreviousFireTime,StartTime,State,TimesTriggered,TimeZoneSidKey FROM CronTrigger where State='ACQUIRED'];

for(CronTrigger ct:con)
{
   system.abortjob(ct.id);
}
```

But Getting below EXCEPTION:

> EXCEPTION: System.StringException: Invalid parameter value
>   "000000000000000" for parameter "id". STACKTRACE: AnonymousBlock: line
>   4, column 1 LINE: 4 COLUMN: 1

**Findings : 
1) CRONJOBDETAILID is null for these job records.
2) DML operation DELETE not allowed on CronTrigger.**

Any Help??

Comment: try like this                                                                                List<CronTrigger> jobsToAbort = [select Id from CronTrigger where CronJobDetail.JobType = '7'];

for (CronTrigger job : jobsToAbort) 
{
    System.abortJob(job.Id);
}

Comment: @KiranMutturu, As mentioned in question, **CRONJOBDETAILID is null for these job records.** Also All CRONJOBDETAIL records in my org are of Type='7', So it would abort all of the jobs. [Not the desired result:(]

Comment: if this is not the case you need to go with the job names only to refer the scheduled jobs here is the link http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_apex_job_name_type.htm

Answer (score 5):

```
// loop through jobs located by name that we need to abort
for(CronTrigger ct : [SELECT Id, CronJobDetail.Name, CronJobDetail.JobType FROM CronTrigger WHERE CronJobDetail.Name like 'WorkOrder%'])
{
  // abort the job, try/catch because the job might not exist
    try
    {
        system.abortJob(ct.id);
    }
    catch (exception e) {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Got the solution for this query from SF support(they just deleted the job instance from backend).

Thanks for the Help Guys:)